# Python - A way to learn and detect text patterns?

Tags: python, regex, machine-learning

**Problem:**

I am given a long list of various position titles for jobs in the IT industry (support or development); I need to automatically categorize them based on the general type of job they represent. For example, IT-support analyst, help desk analyst... etc. Could all belong to the group *IT-Support*.

**Current Approach:**

Currently, I am manually building regex patterns to accomplish this, which change as I encounter new titles which should be included in a group. For example, I originally used the pattern:

*"(HELP|SERVICE) DESK"*

to match *IT-Support* type jobs, and this eventually became:

*"(HELP|SUPPORT|SERVICE) (DESK|ANALYST)"*

which was even more inclusive.

**Question:**

I feel like there should be a fairly intuitive way to automatically build these regex patterns with some sort of algorithm, but I have no idea how this might work... I've read about NLP briefly in the past, but its extremely alien to me... Any suggestions on how I might implement such an algorithm with/without NLP?

**EDIT:**

I'm considering using a decision tree, but it has some limitations which prevent it from working (in this situation) "out-of-the-box"; for example, if I have built the following tree:

**(Service)->(Desk)->(Support) OR ->(Analyst)** *...where Support and Analyst are both children of Desk*

Say I get the string "Level-1 Service Desk Analyst"... This should be categorized using the decision tree above, but it will not inherantly match the tree (since there is no root node named "Level" or "Level-1").

I believe I am heading in the right direction now, but I need additional logic. For example, if I am given the following hypothetical strings:

1. IT Service Desk Analyst
2. Level-1 Help Desk Analyst
3. Computer Service Desk Support

I would like my algorithm to create something like below:

**(Service OR Help)->(Desk)->(Analyst OR Support)** *...where Service and Help are both root nodes, and both Analyst and Support are children of Desk*

Basically, I need the following: **I would like this matching algorithm to be able to reduce the strings it is presented with to a minimal number of sub-strings which effectively match all of the strings in a given cateogory (preferably using a decision tree)**.

If I am not being clear enough, just let me know!

Comment: What's the maximum acceptable error rate for the classifier?

Answer (score 8):

Well, setting a bounty allowed me to learn a lot of new material surrounding this topic, but ultimately I am answering my own question.

I have decided to go with the Pattern module for Python, use a Naive-Bayes classifier.

As the user manually classifies positions, a csv file is generated one line at a time:

"Help Desk Analyst", "Help Desk"
"Service Desk", "Help Desk",
"Jr. Java Developer", "Java Development"
...etc.

My algorithm looks like this (taken from http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-vector#classification):

```
>>> from pattern.vector import Document, NB
>>> from pattern.db import csv
>>>  
>>> nb = NB()
>>> for review, rating in csv('reviews.csv'):
>>>     v = Document(review, type=int(rating), stopwords=True) 
>>>     nb.train(v)
>>> 
>>> print nb.classes
>>> print nb.classify(Document('A good movie!'))
```

...Where **review** and **rating** are **position_text** and **position_group** respectively. Classifier data is saved from one search (and execution of the program) to the next.

Each time the user searches, the algorithm is run (with all previous classifications being taken into account), and the program classifies the positions that are returned with its *best guesses*. Obviously, the more positions are grouped, the more accurate these guesses become.

The next step that I will implement to make this more robust will be to upload user classification data to a central server, which all instances of this software can download from automatically. This way, every user (who willingly contributes data to the project) will contribute to training this software's classification system, and over time, it will become very robust.

Comment: Alterative for dead link to pattern module: https://github.com/clips/pattern/wiki/pattern-vector

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a decision tree approach using individual words as features.

EDIT

The advantage of the decision tree is that it is an "automatic" learning algorithm. You need to just give it the data, and it will build the tree itself. The disadvantage is the need to have the labelled data to train the tree.

How you could do it: the individual words in your titles are features (I'd use them regardless of order). Next you'll need to label some portion of your data manually in something like the following format:

```
HELP,DESK - IT-Support
SERVICE,DESK,ANALYST - IT-Support
SALES,REPRESENTATIVE - Sales
...
```

Where to the left of the hyphen there are features, to the right - the class label.

Next you need to feed this data to the algorithm, and it will learn the words, that discriminate you classes in the best way. The unique advantage of the decision tree here is that you'll be able to see, what are these words. Another advantage is that the tree, probably won't need to use all words in the position labels you have - just enough to be able to reliably classify.

You can, probably, use the decision tree implementation from  [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html).

Comment: No idea what that is, but I'll guess... For each word (from beginning to end) of the sentence I am trying to match, I would create a node on the tree, and then the next word in the sentence would be a child of the previous... is that how it would work? That's a pretty decent idea!

Comment: Not exactly. Decision trees are one of the classification algorithms - you can read more on them starting from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree

Comment: I've updated my question and added a bounty; If you could, please create another (or edit your current) answer to explain how I could solve the situation above using a decision tree!

Comment: I've been reviewing all the answers, and was attempting yours earlier, however I have ran into a problem installing scikit-learn for python; I'm missing numpy, and when I go to install numpy, I'm being told I don't have varsall.bat... any idea what this means? I'm almost sold on your approach with this module, provided I can get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a clustering, or unsupervised, problem rather than a decision tree one (do you know all the roles in advance, and can you provide labelled data).

If it were me, I'd be tempted to build a bag-of-words style representation of your strings and run a generic clustering algorithm (k-means, say) to see what came out. Deciding on a category to assign a new string to is then a fairly simple matching operation (depending on what you use to do the clustering).

You could also look at topic models, with the simplest being Latent Dirichlet Allocation, as being of potential application here. You'd get an assignment to a topic per-word, not per string, but that could be altered if you tweaked the method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; I'm currently going over both yours and the one above to see which I'd like to implement.

Comment: I have one question: I've been tinkering around with Pattern (for python) in this project, and it has modules to classify text... you can select either Naive Bayes, K-Nearest, Single-Layered Average Perceptron, or Support Vector Machine as your algorithm to do the classifying. Which should I use for this situation? And from what I'm understanding reading this documentation, it looks like I'll be training the algorithm for either yours or the answer above (which is fine, because I initially categorize many postings by hand anyway...).

Comment: All of those are supervised methods: you need to provide training data and enumerate all the categories. If you follow my suggestion, you'd need a clustering method. I just had a quick look at the pattern webpage, it looks like it supports k-means, which would work if you convert your descriptions to bags-of-words. You just specify how many categories you want (the k in k-means)

Comment: Ok... there is just one thing I am wondering:

I want the user to be able to group the position titles the way they see fit... Generally their groupings will be like my example above, but they could be slightly more or less specific. Could I cluster the position titles as they are downloaded (I would NOT know how many clusters to create...), have the user create groups (ie. Desktop Support, Network Support), and then assign the positions to their respective groups utilizing the pre-created clusters? As long as the positions are clustered at a detailed enough level, would this work?

Comment: yeah, that sounds possible---I'd suggest starting with offline clustering just to explore your possibilities, but you can certainly look at clustering incrementally as new data arrive, or just assigning the new data to an existing group.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, it looks like you are trying to read in a bunch of job titles and then based on the titles put information into boxes.  You are currently using RegEx, but are looking for better ways doing what your doing.

RegEx and Decision trees are 2 options available, but have you considered going in a completely different direction and instead of searching the Title String for parts ... instead compare the Title String to others that you have already seen and sorted?

For example:

```
ListOfTitles = ['a','b','c','q']
KnownSalesTitles = ['s','q','r']
KnownSupportTitles = ['a','c']
SalesFragments = ['x','y','z']
SupportFragments = ['r','s','t']
for title in ListOfTitles:
  if (title in KnownSalesTitles):
    salesFunction(title)
  elif (title in KnownSupportTitles):
    supportFunction(title)
  else:
    salescount = 0
    supportcount = 0
    for word in title.split(' '):
      if word in SalesFragments:
        salescount++
      if word in SupportFragments:
        supportcount++
    if (salescount > supportcount):
      KnownSalesTitles.append(title)
      salesFunction(title)
    else:
      KnownSupportTitles.append(title)
      supportFunction(title)
```

RegEx works well for finding a specific pattern in a bunch of stuff, but it seems to me that you are wanting to do the exact opposite ... you have a pattern (the title) and you want to check it against a bunch of stuff (known titles)

Just a thought ...

Comment: From a quick review of your algorithm, you're suggesting I do a literal string comparison, followed by a word-for-word match - if the prior attempt does not pan out? I've considered this, but I'm not 100% sure this would work out well enough... for example, if I cannot match the entire string, when I do a word for word comparison, it could match more then one word for a given category, but the words could be ordered differently, and thus have a different meaning... this would always be a possibility. I'm a little more inclined to use a pattern matching algorithm for this kind of flexibility.

Comment: @araisbec yes, like you said it is always a possibility but as your list of things to compare the title string too grows, the method I have proposed will become more and more efficient execution wise (even more so if you use a dictionary or set() instead of a list).  Also in my humble opinion it will also make it much easier to read/edit/modify later on when you need to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

There were suggestions about unsupervised learning, but I recommend to use supervised learning, so you'll categorize 100-200 positions manually, and then algo will do the rest.

There are number of resources, libraries, etc. - look please at "Programming Collective Intelligence" book - they provided good machine learning topics with python examples.

Comment: Yes, I think I am going to go for Supervised learning, since the user will be specifying categories anyway. It fits better.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically generating a regular expression from a list of matching examples is essentially a [grammar induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_induction) problem. There are a few Python libraries that were designed to solve this problem, including [pylstar](https://github.com/gbossert/pylstar).